# Php site deployment?

Tags: php, deployment

new to PHP depolyment. Have solid experience in .NET so deployment is as easy as right click & publish in Visual Studio. Currently, deployment in PHP means connecting to EC2 instance through Filezilla, dragging local folders into Filezilla and wait like forever for it to finish. Is this the standard way to deploy PHP sites or am I missing something here? What if I want to update my website content? Repeat this again? Or upload the modified files? But what if I lose track on what files I have been modified? Git?

Comment: some IDE's provide quite sophisticated PHP deployment support automation and options.

Comment: Git is used to track the code and synchronize to the team, Dragging same code using filezilla will update the code in the server if already exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my prefered workflow

1. Startup local development server (using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html))
2. Make changes
3. Commit to git
4. Push to git
5. (live server pulls from git)

The main benefits of this workflow are:

1. You can see your changes instantly
2. If you break something it will only break locally, if you happend to have pushed the bug to github you can simply revert
3. You don't have to wait for FTP, as git will do the work for you
4. If you are working in a team, you will never overwrite each other's changes over FTP

Comment: That sounds great!